# Apart from Arya, do we see anyone else using a light sword, or only hear about them?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Arya Stark's *Needle* can be described as a [smallsword, or a sort of short rapier](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/77145/46216). I leave the debate on the exact terminology to that older question; what's important is that both the sword and the manner of its use are markedly different to typical Westerosi practice with its armour and heavier swords.  Syrio Forel implies that Braavosi swordsmen fight and arm themselves differently to Westerosi knights, but we only see him (I think) with wooden training swords.

So apart from Arya, does anyone use (fighting or training) any similar light, slender sword on screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Season 5 Episode 9, "The Dance of Dragons", in the fighting pits one of the combatants is an unnamed Braavosi fighter who is wielding a sword similar to Needle.

[image: The Braavosi fighter stabs the Dothraki one] [image: The Braavosi fighter is seen with his sword]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Before this way back in Season 2 Episode 3, "What Is Dead May Never Die", Polliver takes Needle from Arya and kills Lommy with it. He is still seen wearing Needle until Season 4 Episode 1, "Two Swords", when Arya stabs him, takes it back and then kills him with it.

[image: Polliver kills Lommy with Needle] [image: Polliver can be seen wearing Needle as Arya stabs him]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

It's also worth noting we see some Bravos in the *Histories & Lore* episode "Braavos" from Season 5.

[image: Two Bravos with their slender swords]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

The *Histories & Lore* video also has the following relevant information for this image:

> But the beauty of Braavos is not only in her buildings. Braavosi swordsmanship is renowned throughout the world. Our Bravos eschew the armor and longswords of the Westerosi knights, preferring speed, agility, and slender blades. The greatest Bravos call themselves Water Dancers after the custom of dueling upon the Moon Pool near the Sealord's Palace. By tradition, the greatest of all the Bravos is the First Sword, who commands the personal guard of the Sealord and protects his person at all public events. Once chosen, a First Sword serve for life. Inevitably, there are always those who wish to cut that life short to affect some change in policy.

Lastly, whilst you somewhat rule Syrio Forel out in the question I think he is worth mentioning because he does a good job with the wooden practice sword taking out the Lannister soldiers and these swords are somewhat slender.

[image: Syrio faces off against the Lannister soldiers]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

And in Syrio's own words we hear about what the Bravos use as weapons and what their fighting style is like.

> **Syrio Forel:** Tomorrow you will catch it. Now pick it up. That is not the way, boy. This is not a great sword that is needing two hands to swing it.
>
> **Arya Stark:** It's too heavy.
>
> **Syrio Forel:** It is heavy as it needs to be to make you strong. Just so. One hand is all that is needed. Now you are standing all wrong. Turn your body side-face. So. You are skinny. That is good. The target is smaller. Now the grip... Let me see. The grip must be delicate.
>
> **Arya Stark:** What if I drop it?
>
> **Syrio Forel:** The steel must be part of your arm. Can you drop part of your arm? No. Nine years Syrio Forel was first sword to the Sealord of Braavos. He knows these things. You must listen to me, boy.
>
> **Arya Stark:** I'm a girl.
>
> **Syrio Forel:** Boy, girl... You are a sword, that is all. That is the grip. You are not holding a battle-axe. You are holding...
>
> **Arya Stark:** A needle.
>
> **Syrio Forel:** Ahhh… Just so. Now we will begin the dance. Remember, child, this is not the dance of the Westeros we are learning... The knight's dance, hacking and hammering. This is the Bravo's dance... The water dance. It is swift and sudden. All men are made of water, do you know this? If you pierce them, the water leaks out and they die. Now you will try to strike me.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 1 Episode 3, "Lord Snow"</sub>

Comment: In that shot Syrio's sword doesn't look all that slender, but perhaps compared to Meryn Trant's it does

Comment: @ChrisH It's slender-_ish_, gotta remember it's made of wood and is meant to be relatively heavy so it's always going to be bigger than its steel counterpart.

Comment: Yes, the shape of the cross-section is much closer, even if it's wider than needle

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In season 5, Episode 9 we see a Bravosi Gladiator wielding a thin rapier-like sword.

[image]

Comment: We also see Polliver use Needle once, though it isn't much of a fight. But he does continue to wear it openly.

Comment: @svenvo7 a correct technicality - worth an upvote if you post it as an answer (maybe I should add "murder" to the Q)

Comment: *a thin rapier-like sword* in fact with a more rapier-like hilt if I'm not mistaken